# jCanvas - start y from bottom left

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinate, jcanvas

I have created different layers, for example, a roof, a grid and various panels that are set.

I would like to start the y coordinate of the bottom left. Is there an already existing function for this, or is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) should return the y-coordinate at the bottom of the canvas.

Comment: No. Unfortunately, this does'nt work :/

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap all your calls to jcanvas with a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that will "convert" the y-axis values.

Note that you cannot use [rotation](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/rotateCanvas/) by 180° since the [rotate is applied after positionning](http://past.is/wg9O).